# Wget very slow on Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: networking, server, nvidia, cuda, wget

I have been using Ubuntu for about 2 years now, both Desktop and Ubuntu Server. Recently I had a little upgrade to my server (Tesla k80 and a new motherboard + CPU). Now I have run into the following problem. I am trying to install my dependencies and certain weblinks seem to not work, the server is connected by Ethernet. Downloading Anaconda with :
`wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2023.03-Linux-x86_64.sh`
works fine, but when I use:
`wget http://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia/label/cuda-11.6.0/linux-64/libcusolver-11.3.2.55-hebb49eb_0.tar.bz2`
it times out. Now it is not only with this specific link it is with snap installs, Conda installs etc.
When running this on my desktop (which is connected to by Ethernet to the same network) it downloads the files withing seconds. I have tried `speedtest-cli`, and it read 300mb/s down and 50mb/s up, which is as expected. At this point I am quite uncertain what could be the culprit, can someone help me out?

Update: it is the driver. The Intel I219-V is broken in Ubuntu 22.04 (also, 20.18 I think and newer releases for now). I have tried an Ethernet dongle and everything works fine, thus it is the driver. Tried building from source, but that doesn't work because the driver is missing headers (since it is not included in the kernel). So I just have to hope and wait it will be fixed in the future and just rely on my USB dongle for now.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes are:

1. DNS resolution malfunction
2. unsecured (http) connections are blocked.

I tried the web links you provided, they seem to work.

Perform several tests.

### DNS

```
dig repo.anaconda.com
dig conda.anaconda.org
```

Both commands should display the IP addresses of the destination server in the **Answer section**.

My computer received the following responses:

```
dig repo.anaconda.com
...
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
repo.anaconda.com.  600 IN  A   104.16.131.3
repo.anaconda.com.  600 IN  A   104.16.130.3
```

```
dig conda.anaconda.org
...
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
conda.anaconda.org. 84  IN  A   104.17.93.24
conda.anaconda.org. 84  IN  A   104.17.92.24
```

If you do not receive any IP addresses to query for `conda.anaconda.org`, there is a problem with your DNS settings.

### Connection security

Use `https` instead of `http`:

```
wget https://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia/label/cuda-11.6.0/linux-64/libcusolver-11.3.2.55-hebb49eb_0.tar.bz2
```

If you still fail, use debug mode to analyze the causes of the error.

```
wget -d https://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia/label/cuda-11.6.0/linux-64/libcusolver-11.3.2.55-hebb49eb_0.tar.bz2
```

Alternatively, save the wget response to a file. Add `-o mylogfile.txt` to command.

### Edit

It looks like your server doesn't have access to some part of the site. See last part of your log file with error response `ERROR 403: Forbidden`:

```
Host: binstar-cio-packages-prod.s3.amazonaws.com
Range: bytes=1391-
User-Agent: Wget/1.21.2
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
x-amz-request-id: PMYP3KHKEDG6C1SP
x-amz-id-2: mU4kOwo1guna4G5epXUqDIH3LIAKFzFh6gmQ3/brwx2hTssBfhMCKcLt5lO8D+MjZfycNjpvtKcmqIbS3Negu24R74hU2CdndlKhjwSQEEs=
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 28 Mar 2023 09:50:19 GMT
Server: AmazonS3

---response end---
403 Forbidden
Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
Skipping 399 bytes of body: [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Request has expired</Message><X-Amz-Expires>600</X-Amz-Expires><Expires>2023-03-28T09:49:57Z</Expires><ServerTime>2023-03-28T09:50:20Z</ServerTime><RequestId>PMYP3KHKEDG6C1SP</RequestId><HostId>mU4kOwo1guna4G5epXUqDIH3LIAKFzFh6gmQ3/brwx2hTssBfhMCKcLt5lO8D+MjZfycNjpvtKcmqIbS3Negu24R74hU2CdndlKhjwSQEEs=</HostId></Error>] done.
2023-03-28 09:50:22 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Saving HSTS entries to /home/bas/.wget-hsts
```

**Correct response** should be e.g.:

```
Host: binstar-cio-packages-prod.s3.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: Wget/1.21.2
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP požadavek odeslán, program čeká na odpověď…
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: M473rl5RTz5u02x3kjHsdb8KbshDNxlFM90zlU8MCiSYGAnGKOT8QasjHgqA2bPEnLDCOpdMJ6E=
x-amz-request-id: WE3T6BNV235AZDQK
Date: Tue, 28 Mar 2023 10:06:20 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 08 Aug 2022 19:42:10 GMT
ETag: "29a23400fd443750975b89b1b6924b66"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="libcusolver-11.3.2.55-hebb49eb_0.tar.bz2"; filename*=UTF-8''libcusolver-11.3.2.55-hebb49eb_0.tar.bz2
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/x-tar
Server: AmazonS3
Content-Length: 91939740

---response end---
200 OK
Disabling further reuse of socket 4.
Closed 4/SSL 0x0000555c8c35b710
Registered socket 5 for persistent reuse.
Délka: 91939740 (88M) [application/x-tar]
Ukládám do: ‘libcusolver-11.3.2.55-hebb49eb_0.tar.bz2.4’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  487K 3m4s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  244K 4m36s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 67,9M 3m4s
```

So far, I have not thought of what the problem might be, why the web server refuses your access.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have tried the DNS commands and they both give expected results. When it comes to connection security, it still is not able to connect properly.
What is the odd thing, sometimes it is able to go through but does not download the file at all, it would take 124 days. The output of the debugged response can be found [here]( https://docs.google.com/document/d/105ksW0GET5iIW88nvcv_i8tWO6AGdblnnYHa0SnW-IE/edit?usp=sharing).
I am quite at a loss here and really appreciate the help!

Comment: It also does not only come down to wget. Also ```sudo snap install --classic certbot``` or ```conda install -c "nvidia/label/cuda-11.6.0" cuda-toolkit``` get http timeouts, it is too odd especially since they work on my desktop (which is connected on the same network by ethernet)

Comment: Taking a shot in the dark here, but it might be my ethernet and something with drivers: Intel I219-V

Comment: Update: it is the driver. The Intel I219-V is broken in Ubuntu 22.04 (also newer releases for now). I have tried an Ethernet dongle and everything works fine, thus it is the driver. Tried building from source, but that doesn't work because the driver is missing headers (since it is not included in the kernel). So I just have to hope and wait it will be fixed in the future and just rely on my USB dongle for now.